# How to implement onDeletedMessages() for a FirebaseMessagingService?

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can i implement ondeletedmessages() callback method for my firebasemessagingservice in order to do full sync with the app server?

Another question, if the app server didn't send any notification within one month, is onDeletedMessages() called when the  app server is sending a new notification again? (as explain here   https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService.html#onDeletedMessages() in the second case?)

Thank you for response,

Hakoum

Answer (score 0):

I am curious about this issue. 
but I work like this.
For my service, I use two topics. and I find a weird error.

I tested in 3 devices. and I sent messages many times to a device.
and then at a moment the other two devices can't receive messages(from first time).

this is my node.js code.

```
    var topic = 'notice';
    var fcm_message = {
    notification : {
        title : 'title',
        body : 'message',
    },
    data : {
        title:'title',
        body:'test body',
    },
    topic : topic
    };
```

and for a android device which is can't received, I sent message to this device with token like this in backend.

```
   var fcm_message = {
   notification : {
      title : 'title',
      body : 'message',
   },
   data : {
      title:'title',
      body:'test body',
   },
   token : 'DEVICE TOKEN(UNRECEIVED)'
   };
```

then it worked well. (Topic message come in all devices.)

And I think that onDeletedMessages function on android should implement this job.

"It send token to a backend server and a backend send message one more time to a device with this token."

Summery is like this.

1. Backend send messages with topic.(A topic send messages to all devices).
2. In onDeletedMessages callback of android, this device send its token to backend.
3. Backend send a message one more time to specific token.(A Token send a message to one device).